# How to convert negative number in a list of list to 0?

Tags: python, list, numpy

```
[[213, -197, 124, 163], [455, 96, 149, 175], [364, 210, 131, 154], [-22, 119, 243, 308]]
```

How do I convert all negative numbers inside to 0?

```
[[213, 0, 124, 163], [455, 96, 149, 175], [364, 210, 131, 154], [0, 119, 243, 308]]
```

Thank you

Comment: If you don't otherwise need to use `numpy` or `pandas`, it will be simpler, and faster, to stick with a list comprehension.  Or an equivalent inplace modification of the sublists.  numpy code will be simpler to write (if you know that), but creating an array from your list takes time.

Comment: @hpaulj out of curiosity I did time all these answers; the straight list comprehension (Tim's answer) was signficantly (~50%) faster even for very large (1000x1000) inputs where you might think the benefit of vectorisation would outweigh the conversion cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```py
inp = [[213, -197, 124, 163], [455, 96, 149, 175], [364, 210, 131, 154], [-22, 119, 243, 308]]
output = [[0 if x < 0 else x for x in y] for y in inp]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[[213, 0, 124, 163], [455, 96, 149, 175], [364, 210, 131, 154], [0, 119, 243, 308]]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Using property of vectorization of numpy:**

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[213, -197, 124, 163], [455, 96, 149, 175], [364, 210, 131, 154], [-22, 119, 243, 308]])

arr[arr < 0] = 0
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return a new list with elements which are negatives as 0.

```py
def convert(lists):
    p = []
    for nums in lists:
        t = []
        for num in nums:
            t.append(0 if num < 0 else num)
        p.append(t)
    return p 

lists = [[213, -197, 124, 163], [455, 96, 149, 175], [364, 210, 131, 154], [-22, 119, 243, 308]]
result = convert(lists)
print(result)
```

results into

```py
[[213, 0, 124, 163], [455, 96, 149, 175], [364, 210, 131, 154], [0, 119, 243, 308]]
```

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this via np.where-

```
import numpy as np
l = [[213, -197, 124, 163], [455, 96, 149, 175], [364, 210, 131, 154], [-22, 119, 243, 308]]
print((np.where(np.array(l)<0, 0, np.array(l))))
```